# "Kin" Use In Early British Modern English 17th century 1608

Tags: british-english, early-modern-english, kinship-terms, seventeenth-century-english

I am writing a screenplay set in England in the 17th century during the year 1608. I need to know if the use of "kin" (a family) is appropriate in this context. I know that this word did exist back then, but I don't know if it is obsolete by this time or if it is an English word from another part of the world. If so, please suggest an alternative that is true to the year 1608 in England.

Sentences used in my script:

1. I doubt my **kin** shall survive another famine.
2. I had to accept for my **kin** to eat.
3. I do this not only for myself but for my **kin** as well.
4. Thinkest I should leave and let mine **kin** starve?

Comment: Do you have access to the OED? It will show how far back each sense goes. I think this is an archaic word that goes back quite far.

Comment: You can search for words in Shakespeare, who wrote close enough to 1608 that his English would be almost exactly what you're looking for. For example, [see this search for *kin*](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=kin) says that ***kin*** has been around since the 13th century:

> c. 1200, from Old English ***cynn*** "***family***; race; kind, sort, rank; nature" (also "gender, sex," a sense obsolete since Middle English).

OED shows that ***kin*** began to be used with the meaning of family since the 1600s:

> ***kin 1600–*** 
> The group of persons who are related to one; one's kindred, kinsfolk, or relatives, collectively.

Here is an example from 1604:

> You that deny the stocke from whence you came, Thrusting your selfe into some Gentle ***kin***.
> (S. Rowlands, *Looke to It* 11, [OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/kin_n1))

The 1611 KJV Bible does use it in this sense, which shows that ***kin*** was not obsolete in 1608. Here is an example:

> But Jesus said unto them, A prophet is not without honour, but in his own country, and *among his own **kin***, and in his own house. (Mk. 6:4 KJV)

The Greek term for ***kin*** here is *συγγενεῦσιν* (relatives).

It is true, however, that ***kindred*** is used more in the KJV (28 hits, compared to 8 hits for *kin*).

> Now the Lord had said unto Abram, Get thee out of thy country, and from thy ***kindred*** [*συγγενείας*], and from thy father's house, unto a land that I will shew thee: (Gen. 12:1 KJV)

I would say therefore that you are safe using both. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Middle%20English) adds more information:

> Family—both ancestral and in spirit—is what puts the ***“kin”*** in ***kindred***. This word comes from the Old English noun for “kinship,” ***cynrǣden***, which combines ***cynn*** (meaning “***kin***”) and ***ræden***, meaning “***condition***.” ***Kindred*** first entered English as a noun during the Middle Ages. That noun, which can refer to *a group of related individuals or to one's own relatives*, gave rise to the adjective kindred in the 14th century.

So both words were used in 1608.